# Why does this code fall into an infinite loop

Tags: java, concurrency, infinite-loop

I am using jdk1.8.

This code runs directly into an infinite loop, but if I add the commented code, it will run normally. I have tried a lot of codes, as long as the operation of locking is involved, it can run normally.

```
public class StateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        State state = new State();

        new Thread(new Work(state)).start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        state.setStart(true);
        System.out.println("the main thread is finished");

    }

    static class State {

        private boolean isStart = false;

        public boolean isStart() {
            return this.isStart;
        }

        public void setStart(boolean start) {
            this.isStart = start;
        }

    }

    static class Work implements Runnable {

        private State state;

        public Work(State state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            //endless loop
            while (!this.state.isStart()) {
                i++;
                //                if open this code,it will be ok
                //                synchronized (this) {
                //
                //                }
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("work start run after %s loops", i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a `State` instance is not thread-safe.  If one thread calls `setStart` and a second thread calls `isStart`, then the second thread **may not** see the value that the first one set<sup>1</sup>.

You are using `setStart` on a `State` instance so that one instance can signal a second one to end the loop.  If the second thread doesn't see the state change (because of the above) then the loop won't terminate<sup>2</sup>.

Solutions:

1. Change `setStart` and `isStart` to be `synchronized` methods.
2. Declare the `isStart` field to be `volatile`.
3. Instead of writing your own `State` class, use a standard `java.util.concurrent` class to do the synchronization; e.g. `CountDownLatch` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)).

I recommend that you take the time to study the Oracle Java Tutorial Lesson on concurrency:

- [The Java™ Tutorials: Lesson: Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)

---

<sup>1 - The technical explanation for why this can happen is set out in the "Java Memory Model" section of the Java Language Specification.  However, the JLS is NOT written in a way that beginners can understand, and that part is particularly difficult.

2 - In fact, the JLS doesn't say whether the change will be seen or not seen.  The actual behavior is liable to depend on a range of factors that are outside of the programmer's control.</sup>

Comment: The following code can also run normally, but I did not lock the field "isStart"<br/>`            while (!this.state.isStart()) {
                i++;
                synchronized (this) {
                }
            }`

Comment: That's not guaranteed to work.  (Sure, it might work "for you" ... but you are relying on behavior that falls outside of what the JLS actually specifies.)  This is an aspect of Java where you can't just rely on "it seems to work" as an indicator of correctness.  I strongly recommend that you read the Tutorial I linked to ... and don't trust your instinct.

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed the `isStart` value update is visible in the newly created thread.

Since multiple threads access the `isStart` field, you want to mark it as `volatile` to assure the updated variable value will be written always in the main memory and not the CPU cache.

```
static class State {

    private volatile boolean isEnd = false;

    // getters & setters
}
```